# Why does summary() give a different maximum to max()

Tags: r

using R-2.15.2 on Windows XP I get a different maximum from `summary()` than from `max()`.
Why is that so?

Here is the relevant code:

```
> class(dat)
[1] "data.frame"
> dim(dat)
[1] 3850   54
> summary(dat$enrol)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
    26     945    1744    3044    3128  183200 
> max(dat$enrol)
[1] 183151
```

Any ideas why `summary()` rounds the result up?

Best 
Oliver

Comment: What is the result of `str(dat$enrol)` ?

Comment: The result is: 
    num [1:3850] 1089 1100 1011 995 1008 ...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is how the results are printed respecting the `digits` argument. The default is

```
> max(3, getOption("digits")-3)
[1] 4
```

Why R rounds up is just the default rules in use - go to the nearest even digit. We can see this in action with `signif()`:

```
> signif(183151, digits = 4)
[1] 183200
```

which, as `?summary` tells us, is what is used by `summary()` and is controlled by the `digits` argument:

> ```
> digits: integer, used for number formatting with ‘signif()’ (for
>         ‘summary.default’) or ‘format()’ (for ‘summary.data.frame’).
> ```

Read `?signif` for more on the rounding issue.

To get more significant digits, pass a higher number to `summary()` via the `digits` argument.

For example

```
> set.seed(1)
> vec <- c(10, 100, 1e4, 1e5, 1e6) + runif(5)
> summary(vec)
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
     10.3     100.4   10000.0  222000.0  100000.0 1000000.0 
> summary(vec, digits = 7)
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
     10.3     100.4   10000.6  222022.5  100000.9 1000000.0 
> summary(vec, digits = 8)
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
     10.3     100.4   10000.6  222022.5  100000.9 1000000.2
```

Comment: That's very interesting! I always thought significant digits relate to digits after a decimal point...

Comment: @FlorianMans If this Answers your Q, consider accepting it. See the [ask] section of the [faq] for how to do this and why it is important.

Comment: ...wondering if it's time for  world-wide FAQ titled "what is printed is not what the computer is storing internally" :-) .